# Garmin edge 520 strange behaviour

Tags: garmin

Why did my (so far) trusted garmin edge 520, all of a sudden started to behave awkwardly?
1. A well known distance of 18.8klm (as is everyday measured) was measured as 21.2klm
2. Just after the start of a new session the speed meter was stuck to "0.2klm/h" giving false or no  results?
3. Even without wearing my heart rate belt it appeared that I have 72 bpm average pulse?

Comment: 1 and 2: is your speed sensor working well? This may be caused by its fault and Garming trying to get speed from gps only

Comment: How can I tell if speed sensor is working well? Actualy, this is what I am asking...

Comment: First, check if its on - there should be a green led blinking. Second - check that it's connected with the Edge - go to Settings > Sensors (the 2nd ,menu item, not sure for the English word). If it's icon is blinking, it's not connected. Here are some details: https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/speed-cadence-sensor/EN-US/GUID-4392EF45-6170-4666-B026-4278C1E8C6FF-homepage.html

Comment: I checked the divice driving my car: both speed and distance where same with my car's meters. In that case though, it gave me 72bpm av. heart rate, without me wearing the hr belt!

Comment: Well, the car moves much more straight which helps Edge to give an accurate result even without speed sensor. And about HR: I don't know. If I knew, it would ba an answer, not a comment)

Comment: Do you wear a smart watch or other device with other heart beat sensing functionality? I find it hard to believe that your Garmin was getting a reading on heart rate if there weren't any heart rate sensors around. Probably look for a way to do a factory reset on the device or check for firmware upgrades

Comment: @k102 "paired" is the usual word for two devices being connected by something like Bluetooth or ANT.

Comment: If it is the 'revolving' speed sensor at a wheel axle check for a healthy battery. The indications do become erratic once battery life reaches its end.